# Ipod/Iphone acceleration value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer

How to sum all x,y,z acceleration on iPhone to one value, x+y+z ? the real acceleration.

And i want to sum all acceleration within 5 minutes interval?

Ideas?

Thank you very much,
Volter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's representing a vector, so the magnitude of the vector xyz is what you need.
e.g. sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)

Also, be aware that your acceleration values probably include gravity.

Comment: you probably mean: `sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)`

Comment: i was implying that sqr(x) would square x, as in x*x, but I've updated the post for clarity :)

Comment: thanks, but how about the accelerator sensitivity, is very sensitive, always moving, always. How to create a filter for this moving?

Comment: a few approaches, e.g. mean average of last N samples, or, possibly better, take the last N, discard the biggest and smallest, and take an average of the remaining N-2, or, more complex, look at Kalman filtering (http://www.beyond3d.com/content/news/285). There's also another SO thread discussing similar stuff here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272969/how-to-program-smooth-movement-with-the-accelerometer-like-a-labyrinth-game-on-i)