# it is possible to filter out the occasional spikes in sensor readings in C?

Tags: c

psuedocode:

```
if(voltage < 2V)
{
reverse();
}
if(voltage > 2V)
{
forward();
}
```

Problem is my sensor tends to have some spikes in the voltage reading. Example: if it were to be going reverse, the sensor reading might jump past 2V for a split second, executing the forward function.

Is there a way to ignore those split second spikes in C?

Comment: Hello. This question doesn't involve any programming and should be closed. However, you should read about filtering your data. You can start with Kalman filter.

Comment: Maybe count how many times the voltage was above 2V and only do reverse() when it reached a certain amount and reset the counter if it below that.

Comment: Please create a [mre] by showing a complete program which reads sample data. To do so I recommend defining a hard-coded array, explicitly initialised to that sample data sequence. That will allow you to turn your pseudo-code into actual code and  receive proposals as to how to filter your data. A Kalman filter is a very advanced concept, you might be well-served with damping and hysteresis.

Comment: @Eraklon ah thanks thats a simple solution

Comment: When programming PLCs for industrial applications, the common approach is to have a time-hysteresis for input signals like @Eraklon wrote (often including digital sensors too), i.e. new state is accepted only if the value has been *continuously* above a certain threshold for a certain time, which also disregards any noise while crossing the threshold. Another approach this would be a simple low-pass filter (e.g. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761318/69809)), but while this smooths this signal, it doesn't necessarily cancel the spikes.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the voltage to increase and decrease steadily over time you could add logic to enforce gradual increase/decrease.

This could be done by saving an average of the last values and combining this with the new value. You should try a couple of different magic numbers to see which one gives the best result.

```c
int lastvalue = 0;
double magicnumber = 0.6;

while (looping) {
    int thisvalue = (int)(voltage * magicnumber + lastvalue * (1 - magicnumber));
    if (thisvalue > 2) {
        forward();
    else {
        reverse();
    }
}
```

This pattern will prevent sudden changes in the measured value by effectively averaging the current value with all the previous values and weighting the most recent measured values higher than measurements of longer ago.