# Accelerometer Low Pass Filter Smoothing

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, core-motion, lowpass-filter

I am using the device accelerometer and try to smooth the Accelerometer Data `CMAcceleration`.

I am doing this with help of this code:

```
-(void)proccessAccelerometerData:(CMAcceleration)accelData {
    currentAccelX = (kUpdateInterval * accelData.x) + ((1.0 - kUpdateInterval) * currentAccelX);
    currentAccelY = (kUpdateInterval * accelData.y) + ((1.0 - kUpdateInterval) * currentAccelY);
}
```

Which `currentAccelX` and `currentAccelY` is the last accelerometer x and y data.

Now, I have the smooth x and y values, What is my value of x or y to determine id the user move the device left/right/up/down?

Just to make things more clear, for example, let's say that I have 4 buttons, one for each direction left/right/up/down and I want to determine which direction the user user swipe the device? (not swipe gesture). 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "left/right/up/down" depends on how the device is held. The moving average is that, it does not reflect the direction the device is currently moving. Ex moves: u1, u2, d1, u2, u1, d2. The average is u5, the current is d2. The question needs more explanation and what you are trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: @Zaph I edit my question for u m8

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you hold the device in portrait orientation, the x-Axis indicates the movement to the left and right (positive x is to the right and negative x to the left).
The y-Axis indicates the movement of the device up and down (positive y is upwards and negative y is downwards).
The z-Axis indicates the movement of the device forwards and backwards (positive z is towards the user and negative z is away from the user).
There is an info graphic by Apple: [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiacceleration_class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html)

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: So you wanna know how to determine the moving direction of the device relative to the user, no matter if the device is held portrait, upside down or at any other tilt?